# Clickatell parseReplyCallback returning null?

Tags: php, mysql, clickatell

I am trying to get a reply text message from Clickatell using their Rest API, when I call the parseReplyCallback function when their system posts to my page - it seems to be null or I am not sure how to get the variables it is returning. What I would like to do is have all of the variables returned insert into a SQL database so I can use it elsewhere.

I have tried quite a few things, using various styles of getting the variables such as $_POST, $results['text'], $results->text, and so forth each time I can't seem to get any information out of it. I can't just var_dump or anything because I can't see any backend or console so I am pretty much in the blind, hoping someone else is using this system and has it working fine.

```
require __DIR__.'/clickatell/src/Rest.php';
use clickatell\ClickatellException;
use clickatell\Rest;

$Rest = new Rest("j8VKw3sJTZuVfQGVC7jdhA");
// Incoming traffic callbacks (MO/Two Way callbacks)
$Rest->parseReplyCallback(function ($result) {
//mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `SMSCHAT` (`text`) VALUES ('$result')");

$mesageId = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$result['messageId']);
$text = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$result['text']);
$replyMessageId = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$result['replyMessageId']);
$to = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$result['toNumber']);
$from = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$result['fromNumber']);
$charset = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$result['charset']);
$udh = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$result['udh']);
$network = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$result['network']);
$keyword = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$result['keyword']);
$timestamp = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$result['timestamp']);
//do mysqli_query

});
```

I'd like for it to break the result into individual variables (because I plan on doing other things such as an auto-reply, etc) and upload it to the SQL database scrubbed. 
Either doesn't create the table entry or gives me a blank one altogether in that first test where I put the result in the text field.

Answer (score 0):

From a Clickatell point of view, although we understand what you're asking - it's unfortunately outside the scope of support that we offer on our products.

If you would like more information on our REST API functionality, please feel free to find it here: https://www.clickatell.com/developers/api-documentation/rest-api-reply-callback/

If you don't succeed in setting up the callbacks, please feel free to log a support ticket here: https://www.clickatell.com/contact/contact-support/ and one of our team members will reach out and try to assist where possible.